# How to add an object to the session scope using a Struts2 tag?

Tags: java, struts2

I'm using struts 2.2.3.1, loading some objects from the database into an action then displaying them with Freemarker 2.3.16 in a `<ul>`.

The functionality I want is this: when I click on a `<li>` from the `<ul>` I can set the viewed object into the session scope of the application.

For now I have only this:

```
<ul>
    <@s.iterator value="objectList" var="object">       
        <li>
          <@s.url id="myUrl" action="viewObjectPage">
             <@s.set name="objectToBeViewed" value="${object}" scope="session"/>
          </@s.url>

          <@s.a href="%{myUrl}">
            ${object.information?substring(0,7)}...
        </li>
    </@s.iterator>
</ul>
```

I ask if there is a way to put an object into the session using **only** a struts 2 tag.

Comment: That's not what you're asking; you're asking if you can put an object into the session on a *click*. The answer is no, unless you make an Ajax call including enough information to re-load/re-locate the object on the server side. Clicks = JS/client, session = Java/server.

Comment: yeah, you're right, how would I do that?

Comment: Depends entirely on the object and you you create/retrieve/etc it. As long as you send enough info in the request to get an instance you make a normal Ajax request, set the object in session as normal, and you're done, if that's all you really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<s:set>` tag. The **[set](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/set.html)** tag assigns a value to a variable in a specified scope. It is useful when you wish to assign a variable to a complex expression and then simply reference that variable each time rather than the complex expression. This is useful in both cases: when the complex expression takes time (performance improvement) or is hard to read (code readability improvement).

```
<s:set name="personName" value="person.name" scope="session" />
```

**Note:Instead of using EL(${}) inside Struts tags you should use OGNL.**

> <@s.set name="objectToBeViewed" value="**${object}**" scope="session"/>

Replace the EL inside value attribute with OGNL.

> <@s.set name="objectToBeViewed" value="**object**" scope="session"/>

Comment: it doesn't work, that's what I'm using right now as you can see in the example I gave

Comment: so I can add Java types but not objects from classes I made?

Comment: That's because you are using EL(${}) inside set tag. Use OGNL.

Comment: actually it only works without the EL(${}), so remove that and answer will be accepted, otherwise your edit just made the same mistake as I originally did

Comment: the problem actually is that that code only adds the last object from the list in the session

Comment: No, it adds every value in the session but problem is that the variable name is same so new value is assigned in the variable with each iteration.

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted because this way it just puts the last object from the list in the session.

Comment: If you want all objects in session then set the whole list inside session instead of iterating it.

Comment: @user2663337 IMO this answer doesn't answer the question; why is it accepted?

Comment: in part it does answer it actually, if you re-read the question

Comment: @user2663337 No, it doesn't. **Everything that happens on the server side has nothing to do with what happens on the client side.** There is no way to set a *single* object into session from the server side *based on what happens on the client side* before there is client interaction.

Comment: my question actually has 2 questions in it, I think, Ankur answered how I can put an object into the session(as I wrote in my question), but you Dave saw that what I actually want is to put an object into the session according to a click, so I wait an answer I can upvote

Comment: @user2663337 I told you how; S2 tags have nothing to do with this question, as I explained.

Comment: there's no other better answer since Dave didn't provide one to a link to some tutorials or something, so yeah.. I can accept the answer, there are no other pretenders